# Why are pivot columns the basis of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it that when we determine the pivot columns of an m x n matrix $A$, the pivot columns form a basis for the $Range(A)$? I understand that the pivot columns are linearly independent (the reason why we chose them as the pivot columns), but how do we know that they also span the range of $A$?

Also, why is that we're choosing the columns of $A$ to be the vectors that form a basis for $Range(A)$ rather than the columns of $U = rref(A)$?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2521737/265466.

Comment: @Jonathan Wang  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pivot columns form a basis for the $Range(A)$ since they are linearly independent.

We're choosing the columns of $A$ to be the vectors that form a basis for $Range(A)$ rather than the columns of $U = rref(A)$ because $U$ is generally obtained by row operations which modify the column space.

Comment: Aren't the requirements for a basis:
1) Linearly independent vectors
2) Span the given subspace

How do we know that the pivot columns span the subspace as well (in this case, the subspace is Range(A). I get the part on how they're linearly independent.

Comment: Column of A span always a certain subspace with dimension n, to span that subspace you require numbers n of columns linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to showing that the "pivot columns" span the range of $A$:

Can you show that the non-pivot columns can be written as linear combinations of the pivot columns?