# Why do the columns containing leading ones of a matrix give us abasis for the image of a transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $T(x,y,z)=(x+2y-z,y+z,x+y-2x)$. This can be represented with the matrix,

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -2 
\end{bmatrix}

and implementing elementary row operations, can be reduced to

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

I was taught that looking at the columns of the reduced matrix with leading ones, and taking the corresponding columns from the original matrix will yield a basis for $\operatorname{Im}(T)$. So since the reduce matrix has leading ones in column 1 and 2, we take columns 1 and 2 from the original matrix to be a basis for $\operatorname{Im}(T)$. Hence, a basis would be $\{(1,0,1)^T,(2,1,1)^T\}$. Why is this true? Why does it work? How do columns of leading ones give us a basis for the image specifically?

Comment: Any set of linearly independent column vectors will do.  But, when you are doing your row operations, if column k is a combination of the rows before it, your prior operations will have zeroed-out what would have been the corresponding pivot.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2521737/265466), among others on this site. There are several related question in the handy list at right that will answer your question.

Comment: @amd Thanks! your answer really helped.

Answer (score 3):

From the information in the your last matrix you can see that the third column is
minus three times the first plus one time the second. The same happens with the original matrix. So you use only the two first columns to generate the space ${\rm Im}T$ because the image of the third column is a linear combination of the image of the first two.